# Remove repeating text and quotes in Child component in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for some help to remove duplicate words, commas and [] in an array of objects output in a child component.

**PARENT**

```
 <Countries
              v-for="(result, index) in countries"
              :result="result"
              :index="index"              
            />
```

**CHILD**

```
<div v-if="country" >
       {{country}}
            </div> 



mounted () {    
    this.country = [...new Set(this.result.results.country)];
    
  },

data: function () {
    return {
    name: this.result.results.country
}
```

**JSON data**

```
"result": [
"results": {
"country": "Poland, France, Germany, Poland, Latvia, Estonia, Germany, Germany, France", 
},
"results": {
"country": "Poland, France, Germany, Poland, Latvia, Estonia, Germany, Germany, France", 
},
"results": {
"country": "Poland, France, Germany, Germany, France", 
},
"results": {
"country": "Greece, Spain", 
},
.....
```

****This is the OUTPUT I am getting****
[ "G", "r", "e", "c", ", ",", "S", "p", "a", "i", "n",", " ]

It splits the data and removes duplicate letters. How can I get it to just split the words, remove duplicate entries and remove the quotes and the commas?
So the output would just be

Greece, Spain

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using `Set` object is to remove the duplicates from an input which could be any iterable value. i.e. `string` or an `array`.

- If we are passing a string, it will check character by character and remove duplicate characters.
- If we are passing an array, it will check element by element and remove the duplicate elements.

As per your requirement, First you have to convert that countries string into an array by using [`Array.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method and then you can remove the duplicate names.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const country = "Poland, France, Germany, Poland, Latvia, Estonia, Germany, Germany, France";

const arr = country.split(', ');

console.log([...new Set(arr)].join());
```

Comment: @user13928344 Kindly do accept this answer if it helps. So that it will help fellow developers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation here @Rohìt Jíndal. Its very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Try to split the string by `', '` and create the set based on the array from the split result :

```js
 this.country = [...new Set(this.result.results.country.split(', '))];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split the CSV string

```
mounted () {    
    this.country = [...new Set(this.result.results.country.split(',')];
}
```

Comment: Arik and Boussadjra Brahim - thank you. This doesn't remove the duplicates though. So I am still getting 'Name: Greece, Greece for example. How can I remove duplicates also?

Comment: @user13928344 `"Poland, France, Germany, Poland, Latvia, Estonia, Germany, Germany, France"` returns `['Poland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Latvia', 'Estonia']` so it removes the duplicate Germany, France, Poland

Comment: It doesnt remove the duplicates for me unfortunately. Any other suggestions would be great? I get a console error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Comment: Please share the example that you tried out

Comment: mounted () {
    this.country = [...new Set(this.result.results.country.split(','))];
    console.log(this.country)
  },

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(this.result.results.country)` and `console.log(this.country)`

Comment: The results are:
console.log(this.country)  is Greece,Spain,

console.log(this.result.results.country) is Greece,Spain,Greece,Spain,Greece,Spain,Greece,Spain,

So I tried this.country = [...new Set(this.country.split(','))]; But this still displays duplicates